# Pupil Center is Jumping a Lot in Real Time Eye Tracking

Tags: image-processing, real-time, video-processing, eye-tracking, iris-recognition

In my eye tracking project, the pupil center is jumping a lot and I don't see it as a fixed point.

**What should I do?**

My idea is comparing the pupil center and pupil in 2 frames with a threshold but it doesn't help the problem. Another point is camera noise.

**What should I do to reduce the noises?**

I used the [starburst algorithm](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1565386/).

> ***Starburst***: A hybrid algorithm for video-based eye tracking combining feature-based and model-based approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Eye trackers come with 2 types of noise/errors: variable and systematic error. Variable noise is basically the dispersion around the gazed target and the constant drift or the deviation from the gaze target is the systematic noise. For reference, see the following paper:

https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0196348

In your case, its the variable error. Variable error arises due to fatigue, involuntary eye ball vibrations, light, and so on. You can remove it by just filtering the gaze data. However, be careful not to smoothen it too much which might lead to the loss of natural fluctuations inherent in the eye ball.